# JavaScript: How to change keys places dynamically inside an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I need to change keys with values in an array of objects

```
var myArray = [
               {'a' : {'x': ['Bob', 'Rob', 'Mike'], 'y': [4,5,6], 'name': 'a'}}, 
               {'b' : {'x': ['Kris', 'Elen', 'Hanna'], 'y': [10,11,12], 'name': 'b'}} 
]
```

So the result should be like this: (x and y values changed places)

```
var myNewArray = [
    {'a' : {'x': [4,5,6], 'y': ['Bob', 'Rob', 'Mike'], 'name': 'a'}}, 
    {'b' : {'x': [10,11,12], 'y': ['Kris', 'Elen', 'Hanna'], 'name': 'b'}} 
]
```

I have tried to iterate over and save to a new array, but it does not work
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

```
var test = [];

for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(myArray).length; ++i) {
    test['trace' + (i+1)] = {
                            name: myArray[i].name, 
                            x: myArray[i].y, 
                            y: myArray[i].x
    };
}
```

I cannot manually change them, it should be a dynamic approach

Comment: myArray[0] is an object, it should be `myArray[0].a.name` and for myArray[1] it should be `myArray[1].b.name`. You need to get the list of key each item in `myNewArray` here is `a` and `b` then iterate  it

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `test['trace' + (i+1)]`? Since your output doesn't have any keys starting with "trace" I don't see why this is needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use simply swap the values of the two keys and then using `Array#map` to make the transformation over all the objects in the array:

```js
const myArray = [{ 'a': {'x': ['Bob', 'Rob', 'Mike'], 'y': [4, 5, 6],'name': 'a' }},{'b': {'x': ['Kris', 'Elen', 'Hanna'],'y': [10, 11, 12],'name': 'b'}}];

const switchKey = (obj, key1, key2) => {
  const {[key1]: a, [key2]: b} = obj;
  //swap here
  return {...obj, [key1]: b, [key2]: a}
}

const switched = myArray.map(o => {
  let [key, value] = Object.entries(o)[0];
  return {[key] : switchKey(value, "x", "y")};
});
console.log(switched);
```

Comment: Lovely deconstructing - this also works: `const {[key1]: a, [key2]: b, ...rest} = obj;
  return { [key1]: b, [key2]: a, rest}`